# Python: sorting the sum of list

Tags: python, sorting

I have some lists containing the integers.E.g:

```
[ 1, 5, 2 ], [ 2, 3], [7, 8]
```

How can I sort the list by the sum of each lists inside it?

Expected Results:

```
[ 2, 3 ]  [1, 5, 2]   [ 7, 8 ]
```

Should I insert the sum into the first element in the list and then use the sorted function?

```
[ 9, 1, 5, 2 ], [ 5, 2, 3], [ 15, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass a lambda function as the key to sorted:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: sum(x))
```

Or, as pointed out in the comments, simply:

```
sorted(my_list, key=sum)
```

If you want it in descending order, set the parameter reverse to `True`

```
sorted(my_list, key=sum, reverse=True)
```

Comment: You can just do `key=sum`.

Comment: you can just use `key=sum`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` optional parameter in the `sort` function:

```
s =[ [1, 5, 2 ], [ 2, 3], [7, 8]]
new_s = sorted(s, key=lambda x:sum(x))
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3], [1, 5, 2], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: you can just use `key=sum`